# Check if a user is following me using Tweepy

Tags: tweepy

I am using Tweepy and I want to create a script that would unfollow those who don't follow me back. I've created the opposite with ease:

```
for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers).items():
    if not user.following:
        user.follow()
```

But there seems not to be a property holding whether a user is following me back or not in `api.friends`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A year later I've found myself in the need of solving this problem (again). This time I'm a bit more experienced in Python so I could find an approach that works well.

It only needs an API call for every 100 users, which is the max amount of users that can be queried with the `_lookup_friendships` method at once. Well, that, + the unfollows, of course.

```py
for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends, count=100).pages():
    user_ids = [user.id for user in page]
    for relationship in api._lookup_friendships(user_ids):
        if not relationship.is_followed_by:
            logger.info('Unfollowing @%s (%d)',
                        relationship.screen_name, relationship.id)
            try:
                api.destroy_friendship(relationship.id)
            except tweepy.error.TweepError:
                logger.exception('Error unfollowing.')
```

Comment: Using underscored is not a good practice, it denotes "private" method and it would break in future releases. How did you get to `_lookup_friendships`?

Comment: Is http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.followers_ids an option? today?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `API.exists_friendship(user_a, user_b)`. It returns true if `user_a` follows `user_b`.

Reference: http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.exists_friendship

Comment: But that means one API request for each user, right?

Comment: Yes, much like the way you do in your given example.

Comment: As far as I know (correct me if wrong) a Cursor retrieves as many users as the API call allows at once.

Comment: By default, yes. You could restrict it to, say, 200 by `tweepy.Cursor(api.followers).items(200):`

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just use the following codes to get all the social media users one user follows:

```
# Here 1392368760 is just an example user
friends = api.friends_ids(1392368760)
print("This user follow", len(friends), "users")
```

The `friends` is a list, which contains all the people's user ids that the user `1392368760` follows.

In your case, you could just replace the `1392368760` with the user you are interested in and check whether you are in the `friends` list. Moreover, your personal user id could be accessed by the following codes:

```
api.me().id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to accomplish that using Tweepy 4.6.0.

```
my_screen_name = api.get_user(screen_name='YOUR_SCREEN_NAME')
for follower in my_screen_name.friends():
    Status = api.get_friendship(source_id = my_screen_name.id , source_screen_name = my_screen_name.screen_name, target_id = follower.id, target_screen_name = follower.screen_name)
    if Status [0].followed_by:
        print('{} he is following You'.format(follower.screen_name))
    else:
        print('{} he is not following You'.format(follower.screen_name))
        api.destroy_friendship(screen_name = follower.screen_name)
```